# ERROR: partial ordering for explicit instantiation of 'f' is ambiguous when two template function only differ in template argument number

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

The following code cannot compile with clang, but ok with msvc and gcc. WHY?

If I define `f<X, int, int>` function as `template <typename X, int A, int B> void f (X x, position<A>) {}`, the code could compile.

Seems clang will look at the function parameter first and then the template argument?

```
template<int d>
struct position {

};

template <typename X, int A>
void f (X x, position<A>) {}

template <typename X, int A, int B>
void f (X x, position<B>) {}

// This one would work
// template <typename X, int A, int B>
// void f (X x, position<A>) {}


template void f<int, 2>(int x, position<2>);
template void f<int, 2, 1>(int x, position<1>);

int main()
{
    f<int, 2, 1>(1, position<1>());
}
```

code link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PWrbns

Comment: In general `f<int, 2>` doesn't restrict to `f` with 2 template arguments, other arguments might be deduced. Not sure if there is a special case here.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, right. But here, actually, I didn't provide any information for type deduction. So should be other issues causing this?

Comment: `position<2>` allows to deduce B as `2`, so either `f<int, 2, B>` with `B = 2` or `f (X, position<A>)`. You might have `template void f(int x, position<2>);` (`X=int, A=2`).

Comment: `position<2>` allows to deduce B as `2`, so either `f<int, 2, B>` with `B = 2` or `f (X, position<A>)`. You might have `template void f(int x, position<2>);` (`X=int, A=2`).

Comment: @Jarod42 ah yes, make sense. I think your idea explains the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own Answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).